# Wave Dashboard available in Napoli/Community Builder?

Tags: einstein-analytics

Hit a strange limitation, or what seems to be one.  Put my Wave Dashboard inside a Visualforce Page, then created a Lightning Component to house that Visualforce Page so that I can put the Dashboard inside my Napoli template.  When I navigate to the Community Page with this Dashboard it is redirecting me into Wave instead of having the Wave Dashboard be generated and visible on the Visualforce Page as it does when not in the Lightning Component.... am I missing something? It seems odd if I'm not that you can't put Wave into a template.

**vfp**

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardController="Account">

<wave:dashboard dashboardId="0FK21000000006fGAA" 
      showTitle="false"
      showSharing="false"
      height="1500px"
      openLinksInNewWindow="false" 
      hideOnError="false"
      />

</apex:page>
```

**lightning component**

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">
        <iframe src="https://.....salesforce.com/apex/CommunityWaveDashboard"  
        width="100%" height="1500px;" frameBorder="0"/>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this now by creating a Visualforce component and picking the Visualforce page that calls the Wave dashboard.